# How to generate day by day summary for a campaign in Facebook Ads

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

I want to generate a report for a given campaign or (several campaigns I selected) and in the report, each line represents one day. Thus I can do the over the time analysis easily. I can't find how to it. The reports are all at ad sets granularity and thus does not meet my need. Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're calling the [Ad Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api/getting-started/v2.7)

You can get stats at the Ad level by specifying `level=ad` as a parameter
You can get the stats day by day instead of for the entire period you request the data for by specifying `time_increment=1` (it defaults to `time_increment=all_days` )

The more granular data you ask for and the more objects which need to be examined, the more likely it is your call will time out or need to be broken up into smaller chunks - I also recommend [creating your reports asynchronously](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/async/v2.7) if you aren't already